# skipinitialspace in Python csv doens't skip tabs

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse a csv file in Python, but the fields are lined up using tabs, not spaces. So I want to use the skipinitialspace=True option, but it doesn't skip tabs (as the documentation also states). So I came up with the solution below, but I wonder if there is a better solution. Better as in more fast, using less memory or more elegant.

Also I'm posting this question because I was looking for a way to solve this problem and I couldn't find one, so this might help others as well.

Here's what I came up with:

```py
try:
    buffer = io.StringIO()
    with open('myFile.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        for csv_line in csv_file:
            if csv_line == '\n' or csv_line == '\r\n':   #skip empty line
                continue
            if csv_line[:1] == '#':                      #skip lines that start with # as they are commented out
                continue
            buffer.write(csv_line.replace('\t', ' '))    #replace all tabs with spaces (otherwise skipinitialspace doesn't work)
    buffer.seek(0)                                       #go back to the beginning of the buffer
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(buffer, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            row = [s.strip() for s in row]              #strip leading and trailing whitespace (tabs, spaces, ...)
            if (len(row) == 0) or (len(row[0]) == 0):   #skip empty line
                continue
            #ignore everything that starts with a #
            if row[0][:1] == '#':                       #skip lines that start with # as they are commented out
                continue
            #--- DO STUFF HERE TO PROCESS DATA ---
    except csv.Error as e:
        return (f'''CSV error: {e}''')
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    return (f'''Error found in CSV file. Make sure it is in UTF-8 format: {e}''')
except OSError as e:
    return ('''Error opening menu file: {e}''')
```

---

Update with extra explanantion:

In order for my csv file to be parsed correctly, initial tabs need to be stripped *before* the csv.reader does its job.

E.g (with skipinitialspace=False):

```py
"Number1";"Num;ber2" > ['Number1'],['Num;ber2']   (correct)
```

But:

```py
"Number1"; "Num;ber2" > ['Number1'],[' "Num'],['ber2"']   (not what I need)
```

I can set skipinitialspace=True, but in my case the space after the semicolon is a tab, and I still get the second result, which is not what I need. So I'm replacing *all* tabs with spaces. Using strip() here is not enough as strip() only strips whitespace at the beginning and end of a line, and my tabs are in the middle. I used the solution stated above, but I wonder if it can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

strip() strips of all whitespace characters including tabs. so you donot need to separately clear initial tabs or additional \r in case of \r\n at end of a line ...if you are going to strip  every item

strip() strips leading or trailing ....space, tab, linefeed, return, formfeed, and vertical tab.

Comment: Strip() indeed strips all whitespace, not just spaces - but that doesn't answer my question. I posted some more explanation in an update.